# html how to play sound using aria attribute

Tags: html, wai-aria

In my page has a dialog form. In dialog has a button close.
The close button may not be obvious to the visually impaired. 
I wants user to hear “close the dialog”  when focusing on the close button in the dialog. But not using a source audio file.

My friend has suggest use HTML ARIA.
Anyone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `aria-label`.

[Taken from this example from MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute)

```
<button aria-label="Close" onclick="myDialog.close()">X</button>
```

Also explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040485/4278038)

Comment: ok, i understood aria attr. could you suggest to me any screen reader which can play sound. I have install Thunder Screenreader, but look like it not work fine. Thanks

Comment: I don't actually have experience with screenreaders, only some knowledge of coding for it in HTML...