# Javascript: How to create a browser bookmarklet to edit a file in Github?

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarklet

I have a javascript bookmarklet that helps me in committing GitHub commit:

```
 document.getElementById('submit-file').click();.
```

I was wondering how to make a similar bookmarklet to EDIT the GitHub file?

I am new to javascript and still in the learning phase so this is kind of taking days me to figure out how to do this

## Update as per comments

FWIW, In fact, I was trying to modify an Alfred workflow (MacOS application to automate tasks) and the app allows us to click the "commit" button in github pages and I was trying to modify it so that now I can edit the current document in github.

Outline of app:

First part:

```
document.getElementById('submit-file').click();
```

Second part:

```
const bookmarklet_code="{query}"
const frontmost_app_name = Application('System Events').applicationProcesses.where({ frontmost: true }).name()[0]
const frontmost_app = Application(frontmost_app_name)

if (['Google Chrome','Google Chrome Canary','Chromium'].indexOf(frontmost_app_name) > -1) {
  frontmost_app.windows[0].activeTab.url = 'javascript:' + bookmarklet_code
} else if (['Safari', 'Safari Technology Preview', 'Webkit'].indexOf(frontmost_app_name) > -1) {
  frontmost_app.doJavaScript(bookmarklet_code, { in: frontmost_app.documents[0] })
} else {
  throw new Error('You need a supported browser as your frontmost app')
}
```

Comment: Does the bookmarklet you’re to referring to have the address `javascript:document.getElementById('submit-file').click();` (not `document.getElementById('submit-file').click();.`)? Can you also please provide an address to somewhere on GitHub where your existing bookmarklet functions properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.querySelector('[aria-label="Edit this file"]').click();
```

It finds the **Edit** button based on [Aria-Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039910/what-is-aria-label-and-how-should-i-use-it) and clicks it.