# ARIA Labels in HTML: Inside or Outside the Element?"

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm working on improving the accessibility of my website and have a question regarding the placement of `ARIA` labels in HTML. When using `ARIA` attributes like `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`, is it considered best practice to place them inside the element they are labeling or outside? For instance, which of the following is the recommended approach:

```js
<div class="container" aria-label="testing">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

OR

```js
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" aria-label="testing" />
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you check this link?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039910/what-is-aria-label-and-how-should-i-use-it, and this other one: https://www.aditus.io/aria/aria-label/

Comment: You can find further details on the official **`W3C`** site where the **`WCAG 2.0`** guidelines were defined. https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA6.html#:~:text=The%20aria%2Dlabel%20attribute%20provides,will%20know%20what%20it%20is. **`Example 2: A phone number with multiple fields`**: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA14.html#ARIA14-ex2

Comment: The first of these won't work, because a `div` with no `role` is meaningless to assistive technology. The second is fine, assuming you want the text input to have the label `testing`. But, following the [first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1), why not simply use a native HTML `label` instead? This also benefits non-assitive-technology users, by making it visually clear what the label is, and giving a larger click target to start entering input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is your second example.
The first one won't work.

The attribute aria-label must be put on the element you are labelling. Putting it in another element has no effect.
Labelling elements with aria-label only work if the element is interactive and focusable, or if it has an explicit role assigned. This is the case of input fields and links, but not `<div>` in the normal case.

The attribute aria-labelledby works the same as aria-label, except that it refers to another element containing the label, instead of giving a label dirrectly. It also has the same limitations.

For similarity as how native `<label>` works, it's better to place the labelling element before or after the labelled element, but not as a parent. In other words:

```
<label for="X">...</label>
<input id="X"/>
```

Works better than:

```
<label>...
<input/>
</label>
```

So similarly,

```
<div id="X">...</div>
<input aria-labelledby="X"/>
```

Works better than:

```
<div id="X">...
<input aria-labelledby="X"/>
</div>
```

IN this later case, it's possible that the label is read twice.

If you have the possibility to do so, though, it would be much better to use a real `<label>` element instead of aria-label or aria-labelledby attributes.
The first rule of ARIA says that you shouldn't use ARIA if you can do it simpler in another way, and in this case using native `<label>` is a very easy solution to not use ARIA. Attributes aria-label and aria-labelledby should be used only when it's not very practical to have a `<label>`.

Remember that `<label>` give a bonus feature for free, the possibility to click on it to focus the element it is attached to. It may look a bit useless for you, but it's in fact extremely important for partially sighted people, or those who have imprecise hand movements, for example.

Comment: Thanks it's helped me and the examples were perfect too!